# XPath expression evaluates differently in Java than in XML Spy?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

These XPath expressions evaluate differntly in Java than they do in XML Spy. In order to see what I mean, you need to run the Java code, see what outputs to the console and paste each xPath expression to XML Spy to see how different the answers are.  Can anyone tell me why and what to do about it?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder;

        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        //wherever you happen to stick the xml file
        Document doc = builder.parse("C:\\SVN\\Claims_Extract_Bridge\\src\\config\\Templates.xml");

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xpf.newXPath();

        //This one works where it only has to find one node
        XPathExpression xpath1 = xPath.compile("//Template[Rules/Rule/TreatmentSetting='IO'  and Rules/Rule/DiagnosisCodes/DiagnosisRange[substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisStart, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)<='291005'  and substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisEnd, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)>='291005' ] and Rules/Rule/ProcedureCodes/ProcedureRange[ProcedureStart<='0906'  and ProcedureEnd>='0906' ]]");

        NodeList diagnosisRangeList = (NodeList)xpath1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Should return 1 Template node from XML file and it does, see what I mean:  " + diagnosisRangeList.getLength() + " node(s)");

        //This one should return 1 nodes (it does in XML Spy) but returns 0?
        xpath1 = xPath.compile("//Template[Rules/Rule/TreatmentSetting='PO'  and Rules/Rule/DiagnosisCodes/DiagnosisRange[substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisStart, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)<='242000'  and substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisEnd, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)>='242000' ] and Rules/Rule/ProcedureCodes/ProcedureRange[ProcedureStart<='59841'  and ProcedureEnd>='59841' ]]");
        diagnosisRangeList = (NodeList)xpath1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Should return 1 node from XML file but instead returns 0, see what I mean:  " + diagnosisRangeList.getLength() + " nodes");

        //This one returns 2 nodes in XML SPY but 0 nodes in Java? 
        xpath1 = xPath.compile("//Template[Rules/Rule/DiagnosisCodes/DiagnosisRange[substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisStart, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)<='62602'  and substring(concat(translate(DiagnosisEnd, '.', '0'), '0000000000'), 1, 6)>='62602' ] and Rules/Rule/ProcedureCodes/ProcedureRange[ProcedureStart<='55250'  and ProcedureEnd>='55250' ]]");
        diagnosisRangeList = (NodeList)xpath1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Should return 2 nodes from XML file but instead returns 0, see what I mean:  " + diagnosisRangeList.getLength() + " nodes");

    }
}
```

Here is the XML File being read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Templates>
    <Template>
        <TemplateCode>GLOB</TemplateCode>
        <Units>9999</Units>
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <TreatmentSetting>PO</TreatmentSetting>
                <DiagnosisCodes>
                    <DiagnosisRange>
                        <DiagnosisStart>0</DiagnosisStart>
                        <DiagnosisEnd>ZZZZZZ</DiagnosisEnd>
                    </DiagnosisRange>
                </DiagnosisCodes>
                <ProcedureCodes>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>99213</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>99213</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                </ProcedureCodes>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <TemplateCode>ME004</TemplateCode>
        <Units>1:1</Units>
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <TreatmentSetting>H</TreatmentSetting>
                <DiagnosisCodes>
                    <DiagnosisRange>
                        <DiagnosisStart>0</DiagnosisStart>
                        <DiagnosisEnd>ZZZZZZ</DiagnosisEnd>
                    </DiagnosisRange>
                </DiagnosisCodes>
                <ProcedureCodes>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>99341</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>99345</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                </ProcedureCodes>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <TemplateCode>ME004</TemplateCode>
        <Units>1:3</Units>
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <TreatmentSetting>PO</TreatmentSetting>
                <DiagnosisCodes>
                    <DiagnosisRange>
                        <DiagnosisStart>0</DiagnosisStart>
                        <DiagnosisEnd>ZZZZZZ</DiagnosisEnd>
                    </DiagnosisRange>
                </DiagnosisCodes>
                <ProcedureCodes>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>92511</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>92608</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>92611</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>96999</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                </ProcedureCodes>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <TemplateCode>ME011</TemplateCode>
        <Units>1:1</Units>
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <TreatmentSetting>IO</TreatmentSetting>
                <DiagnosisCodes>
                    <DiagnosisRange>
                        <DiagnosisStart>290.00</DiagnosisStart>
                        <DiagnosisEnd>290.99</DiagnosisEnd>
                    </DiagnosisRange>
                </DiagnosisCodes>
                <ProcedureCodes>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>0905</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>0905</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>0912</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>0912</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                </ProcedureCodes>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <TreatmentSetting>IO</TreatmentSetting>
                <DiagnosisCodes>
                    <DiagnosisRange>
                        <DiagnosisStart>303.00</DiagnosisStart>
                        <DiagnosisEnd>305.99</DiagnosisEnd>
                    </DiagnosisRange>
                </DiagnosisCodes>
                <ProcedureCodes>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>0906</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>0906</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                    <ProcedureRange>
                        <ProcedureStart>0912</ProcedureStart>
                        <ProcedureEnd>0913</ProcedureEnd>
                    </ProcedureRange>
                </ProcedureCodes>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
    </Template>
</Templates>
```

Comment: Why don't you include here how the outputs are different?

Comment: Which data type do you want to compare with `<=`? XPath 1.0 only supports number based comparison so perhaps your Java XPath implementation does number based comparison while XML Spy might do string based comparison.

Comment: Really? Did not know that. I am told that Xpath 2.0 might not have that issue but I am not sure how to just snap my fingers and control using 2.0 instead of 1.0. Can you direct me on what I should do about this?  Perhaps my only recourse here is to enumerate all the nodes of the file using Java to do the compares?

Comment: Martin, I did, my System.out.println commands show you the number of nodes retreived by java and the xpath expression used to evaluate, if you paste that into XML spy for the file I pasted, you will see the nodes retreived there.

Comment: The fact that XML spy can properly evaluate my xpath expression should give me hope right?  Perhaps it is just a matter of using a different parser in Java, but I am not entirely sure how to do that in Java.

Comment: To use XPath 2.0 you need to use an XPath 2.0 implementation like Saxon 9. But I am not yet sure the issue I commented on is the problem, I tried your file now and it does not compile and when I try to use different variables it does not find any nodes for any expression. Consider to edit and provide an XML and a complete Java sample allowing us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just corrected the code so it will compile and run for you.

Comment: I am on a tablet right now so I can't test the Java code but I have had a closer look at the Xml values and I think you have values in there like `ZZZZZZ` where XPath 1.0 number comparison does not make sense. Thus if you want to compare such values with the operators `<` or `<=` as strings then you indeed need to look for an XPath 2.0 or Xquery 1.0 implementation.

Comment: Ok, can you direct me on how to do that?

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xpath-api/s9api-xpath on how to use Saxon 9 and XPath 2.0 from Java.

Comment: Having trouble loading the page, will try googling, thanks!